# Strip Specific Word in VBA for each chart

Tags: vba, excel, legend

So I loop through each chart using the following code:

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate

    'Do something with the chart...
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    Selection.Left = 108.499
    Selection.Width = 405.5
    Selection.Height = 36.248
    Selection.Top = 201.85
    Selection.Left = 63.499
    Selection.Top = 330.85
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Height = 246.69
    Selection.Width = 445.028

  Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

This makes each chart a specific size and I was thinking that I can modify the following vba code to strip the word `"Test:` out of `Test: abc` the legend and then the resulting legend would be `abc`. I think that I can modify the following code, but I am not sure how to to do this. :

```
For i = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
If ActiveChart.Legend(i)= "Test: *" Then
ActiveChart.Legend(i) **what I think needs to be modified**
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to strip a specific word, you can

- Replace the prefix using the function `Replace()`
- Take the sub string using the function `Mid()`

Here's the demo code

```
Sub stripDemo()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Test: my legend"
    Debug.Print Replace(str, "Test: ", "")
    Debug.Print Mid(str, 7, Len(str) - 6)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

So when the code is applied to chart, it becomes :

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate
    ' iterate the series collection
    ' replace the prefixe "Tests: " with ""
    For Each sr In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      If Len(sr.Name) > 6 And Left(sr.Name, 6) = "Test: " Then
        sr.Name = Replace(sr.Name, "Test: ", "")
      End If
    Next sr
  Next cht
Next sht
```

Comment: So would this be possible without needing to define all the legends because I want to be able to not have to hard code all the different legends.